# Laravel Datatables Getting First Row of the query

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-5

I'm using yajra's laravel/datatables plugin and I want to send only the first row of every group from the query sorted according to date of the record descending. This is my query :

```php
$qsrecords = QualityScore::where('clientID', '=', $user['id'])
       ->whereBetween('day', array($startDate, $endDate))
       ->where($desiredValue, $operator, $quantity)
       ->where('previousQualityScore','!=','0');
```

This query returns every record for this given user id like :

```
Client ID | Keyword ID | Quality Score |     Date
   2           81            8            21.08.2016
   2           42            9            19.08.2016
   2           81            7            16.08.2016
   2           42            5            14.08.2016
```

as you can see, ı got 2 different keywords and my query is giving that output.

but i want my query to generate results like :

```
Client ID | Keyword ID | Quality Score |     Date
   2           81            8            21.08.2016
   2           42            9            19.08.2016
```

**Only the last records of every keyword.** That's I want to achieve.

The way i send the query to view :

```
    // Send data to view via datatables plugin
    return Datatables::of($qsrecords)->make(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
QualityScore::select( * , DB::raw('MAX(date) as date'))
              ->where('clientID', '=', $user['id'])
             ->whereBetween('day', array($startDate, $endDate))
             ->where($desiredValue, $operator, $quantity)
             ->where('previousQualityScore','!=','0');
             ->groupBy('keyword_id')
               ->get();
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. laravel gives parseError: syntax error, unexpected '*' when i use your query. I should say that, since i'm using datatables plugin, i'm not able to write a "->get()" at the end of the query.

Comment: ı've edited my question to show you the way i send this query to datatables plugin for creating view.

Comment: Oops sry for that  parseError: syntax error. I should have tried that select (*) .Cheers you figured it out.

Comment: actually, now i'm facing with another problem. max(day) is giving me the lastest record's day but other fields for that row like qualityscore, previous qualityscore are not this day's informations...

Comment: and i also tried (*) and it gave the same error as above example

Comment: ok then i need to  try it out on system... will post the answer when I'm done.

Comment: ok, now i've solved the issue. i'll post an answer post to question. Thanks for your effort and time really much Kiran.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've figured it out! I've changed the way i approach to this issue but the following code has solved the issue, thanks @Kiran-sadvilkar for suggestions.

```
$groupByMaxDateQuery = ' SELECT qs.adGroup,qs.keyword, qs.previousQualityScore, qs.qualityScore, qs.qualityScoreDifference, qs.day 
                FROM homestead.qualityScore AS qs
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT adGroupID, keywordID, max(day) 
                    AS MaxDay 
                    FROM homestead.qualityScore 
                    GROUP BY adGroupID,keywordID
                )
                innerTable ON qs.adGroupID = innerTable.adGroupID 
                    AND qs.keywordID = innerTable.keywordID 
                    AND qs.day = innerTable.MaxDay
                WHERE qs.clientID = '.$user['id'].' AND 
                    qs.day BETWEEN "'.$startDate.'" AND "'.$endDate.'" AND 
                    qs.'.$desiredValue.' '.$operator.' '.$quantity.' AND 
                    qs.previousQualityScore != 0
                ';

    // Pull data from database with current conditions
    $qsrecords = DB::table(DB::raw("($groupByMaxDateQuery) as qs"));
```

As a result i've decided to use a raw sql query and now it works...